# Who is Goddess Hri?

Tags: vedas, puranas, devi, goddess

Hri is a Goddess mentioned in some scripture, though she is not a famous goddess there are places where she is mentioned like

> Natsyashastra 3(86,87) let mothers such as Sarasvati, Dhriti, Medha,**Hri**, Sri, Lakshmi protect you and give you success.

And I also read in a site that according to Puranas Devi Hri is the daughter of Prajapati Daksha, wife of Dharma and mother of Prasarya.The Shatapata Brhamana also says that Devi Hri is born from Lord Prajapati and also in Purusha Sukta of Yajurveda

> **Hri** and Lakshmi are thy wives: each side of thee are
>   Day and Night.

So I want to know

**Who is Goddess Hri?**

**In which scriptures she Is mentioned?**

Comment: Purusha Sukta also has word "Hri". *Hrisca te Lakshmisca patnyou*.. Hri is Parvati devi for Shaivas/Shaktas and Nila Devi for Vaishnavas.

Comment: @TheDestroyer - Hri is also mentioned in Bhagvat purana.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar You Can Answer from refence from Bhagavata puran

Comment: @TheDestroyer Is She Mentioned In Itihasas(Ramayana or mahabharata?

Comment: "Hri" in Sanskrit means modest women. But then again all dharma patnis are modest. Hri could be bhu devi.